# Foldable, multipart helicopter blades

Tags: engineering, flight, flying-machines

What would it take to build helicopter blades that can fold in several parts?

This is the continuation of [a question on Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/66267/are-there-any-helicopter-blades-that-fold-in-the-middle). Unfortunately, there have been no use case for this for existing helicopters, so no-one has spent millions trying to work out if it was possible, let alone how to do it. As far as real life is concerned, folding helicopter blades at the rotor hub is good enough. As such, the question seem impossible to answer on a more reality-grounded place like Aviation, hence why it is continued here.

Assume that I have developed a magical [helipack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpack_helicopter), or some other sort of ultracompact helicopter with a magical black-box power source. The helicopter itself is either contra-rotating or tip-jet to avoid the need of a tail rotor.

The problem is that while the helicopter itself is extremely compact, there is this enormous rotor and its long, long blades that get in the way when not flying.

Folding them at the rotor hub, as is done with conventional helicopters, helps a bit. However, blades of several metres long don't fit into the nice little backpack like everything else. For that, I need rotor blades that fold in several parts as well.

**How would a rotor blade that can fold in several parts be designed?** How good would it be as rotor blades? How much more would it mass?

Less-than-ideal blade efficiency is an acceptable tradeoff, as is (obviously) increased complexity. As the outer edge contributes more than the center, it is also acceptable to have the blade not generate lift from the inner parts, as long as the loss of efficiency is not too severe. However, the thing must be reasonably safe, so we want to avoid it falling apart as soon as one pin breaks.

If the design would be different for a conventional (contra-rotating) system or a tip-jet, please point out the differences (or their absence).

Bonus points if the blade can unfold by spinning it or in some other automatic way, so the user can press a button, deploy the rotor and have it open by spinning - allowing them to instantly fly off while screaming "I'll get you next time" at the heroes who just foiled their plans. Having to stop and unfold them by hand would simply not be as theatrical.

Extra-bonus points if it can also fold back automatically after stopping it. Again, not having it to fold it yourself right after landing, wasting no time to Save the Day, just looks better.

Comment: The problem here is not "how can it be designed" but "can you imagine realistic materials that can be relaibly used".  The forces involved are very high and they perform critical functions.  As it stands, however, this might be too broad - it's an open ended set of list questions at the moment.

Comment: This isn't answer but I think your protagonist should just get one of these https://www.pal-v.com/en/explore-pal-v

Comment: Presumably you feel that helicopters are already too safe and too reliable. Would you consider helicopter-like alternatives as valid answers?

Comment: @StarfishPrime That could be interesting, though what do you mean by "helicopter-like"? Autogyres cannot take off vertically as far as I am aware, and turbines would not have blades to fold (and are less energetically efficient as far as I can tell)...

Comment: @Eth your question does not state that vertical takeoff or landing are an absolute requirement, nor does it say that the system couldn't be combined with some other takeoff assisting mechanism ;-)

Comment: @StarfishPrime Fair enough, then!

Comment: @TrevorD This thing is beautiful and stupid and I love it! It may be a bit too big to fit in a backpack, though.

Comment: @StephenG Not sure how it is too broad. The question is about a specific part (multi-folding helicopter blade) for a specific use (light helicopter), though in two configurations (counter-rotating/tipjet). If material strength sets a limit to what is possible, that is a valid answer, though what this limit is is important. For example, slower rotor blades could help, but by how much?

Comment: This site has a lot of posts about space elevators and the materials that can be used to build them. It may be worth perusing those posts because many of them talk about the need for the elevator to be segmented in order to dynamically stabilize and/or dodge attacking planes/missiles.

Answer (score 7):

Different choppers with folding blades fold them in different distances from the hub. Look at the [AH-1Z Viper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_AH-1Z_Viper):

[image: Bell AH-1Z]

[As Ash said](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/151010/21222), where and how wings are folded has to do mostly with material strength. You may wish to have joints like those of the [V-22 Osprey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey):

[image: MV-22 Osprey]

Its blades are short compared to its body, and the joint seems pretty sturdy compared to regular civilian choppers with folding blades.

Comment: This is interesting, though those designs still have the folding point close to the rotor hub - probably because they have no reason to do otherwise. What can we deduce from it about folding points further along the blade?

Comment: @Eth we can deduce that it takes stronger materials and different storage setups to justify that. Most folding blade designs IRL are meant to allow helicopters to be stored in long, narrow places.

Answer (score 6):

The rotor design on a toy helicopter I saw recently suggests its a matter of material strength rather than any technical difficulty. Those blades were in three sections that folded away for storage and folded out under tension when spun up. The problem is that those wings had to be made of cast aluminium with high tensile steel pins and they were on the order of only 100-120mm long when extended; helipacks, like the ones in the linked article, have 6m+ wingspans so the forces acting on the wing blades are much greater. Unfortunately I don't have the expertise to work out what would be required, nor the time, or patience, to work it out from first principles today, hopefully someone else can help you with that.

Answer (score 3):

A good estimating starting point is to look at the force on a point of the blade, and compare the relative force for a hinge point near the root against one near the middle or the end of the blade. For simplicity, I am thinking of what I will call a unit rotor blade: 1 unit long, mass of 1 unit, of constant geometry and therefore constant mass per length. Consider the [formula for the force required to keep a mass on a circular path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force):
$$
f_c = m\frac{v^2}{r}
$$
where $f_c$ is the force, $v$ the linear velocity of the mass, $m$ is the mass value, and $r$ the radius of the circular path it is traveling. But the linear velocity is affected by the radius, where:
$$
v = \dot\theta r
$$

$\dot\theta$ is the angular velocity, and $r$ is the radius of the circular path. When we substitute this in to our first equation and simplify we get:
$$
f_c = m \dot\theta^2 r
$$

I am going to assume a constant angular rate. Unless the blade is a noodle of some kind, it will either all rotate at the same angular rate, or it will break into pieces as different parts move past each other. Since we want a functioning helipack, I think this is a safe assumption. Since I assumed a mass of 1 and a blade length of 1, the mass at any point radius $r$ is equal to $(1-r)$. Substituting that in and eliding angular rate for the moment, we get
$$
f_c \approx (1 - r)r = r - r^2
$$

So what does this tell us? Lets look at a graph:

[image: Graph of force]

As you can see, the relative force on the blade is highest near the center. This is a big problem, because if we want blades the fold down small, we are going to need blades that fold closer the the center than a traditional folding helicopter blade. If you compare a joint at 10% of the blade length with one at 50%, the one at 50% will need to be ~2.8 times stronger. If you want to fold the blades at 1/3 and 2/3 of the length, then you need two joints, each stronger by a factor of ~2.5.

This issue is probably somewhat ameliorated by the fact that most wings (and rotors are wings) will taper to the tip, but that is only possible because the centripetal force we have considered so far is not the only force, you also have to account for both lift and drag. If you assume that those are constant along the wing (possibly generous, I'm not sure), then those forces are somewhat less for joints further out. However, you also have to account for the fact that a joint with more force is probably heavier, and shifting that extra mass closer to the end of the blade means more of the blade will have to support it centripetally, and for centripetal force that also means that more mass will be concentrated in parts of the blade that are being spun faster, potentially further increasing the mass of the rigid sections.

From a reliability standpoint, there's no way it does not fall apart when one pin breaks. At high rotational speed, there's no graceful way to recover from becoming unbalanced like that. And that is ignoring the fact that even fixed rotor helicopters already have single points of failure, the proverbial [Jesus Nut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_nut) that holds the main rotor in place.

With all that in mind, and with the variety of exotic materials and low [factors of safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_of_safety#Choosing_design_factors) already in use for real world helicopters, I think it might be worth either thinking of some fictional material that makes this whole thing feasible, or trying to avoid a jointed rotor. You could think about something that is flexible or telescoping and deploys with the spin of the blades, though perhaps that is similarly infeasible, only for engineering reasons I am not aware of.

Comment: Very interesting analysis, thanks!
Since I asked the question, I have also been suggested to look into thin-wings for the helicopter blade shape. They have lower wing loading but otherwise good performances still. This could allow it to be rolled maybe, or to be folded like insect wings, which use sometimes very clever ways to store the wings under the elytron.
Given your conclusions, it seems that those alternate solutions may be more promising, or at least worth looking into.